# Problems about concurrent task in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, fastapi, uvicorn

**dear community**

I've tried to execute async def in FastAPI app.
the workflow is crate FastAPI service to recieve from end-user requests and send it to another service such as DB Writer service.

first, I've create async def for send request with aiosonic library
Here's the code

```
import aiosonic
from aiosonic.timeout import Timeouts
async def db_writer_requests(arrival_input, prediction_out) :
   client = aiosonic.HTTPClient()  
   timeouts_settings = Timeouts(sock_connect = 10,sock_read = 10) 
   await client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/motor/writer/test1',
                headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                json = arrival_input,
                timeouts = timeouts_settings)
client.shutdown()
```

Here's main app

```
@app.post('/api/motor/test')
async def manager_api(raw_input:arrival_requests) :
    depart_json = dict(raw_input)
    inc_preds, model_error = await predict_requests(depart_json)
    if (inc_preds == None) or (inc_preds['status_code'] != 200) :
        return inc_preds if model_error == None else model_error 
    else :
        mlid = uuid.uuid4()
        pred_output = model_output(
                predict_uuid = str(mlid),
                net_premium = str(inc_preds["result"]["data"]["net_premium"]),
                car_repair = str(inc_preds["result"]["data"]["car_repair"]),
                place_repair = str(inc_preds["result"]["data"]["place_repair"]),
                insurer_tier = str(inc_preds["result"]["data"]["insurer_tier"])
            )
        send_msg = good_response_msg(
            status = 'OK',
            status_code = 200,
            result = data(
                data = pred_output
            )
        )
    await db_writer_requests(depart_json,dict(pred_output))
    return send_msg
```

when I've tried to send request.

case 1 I've not to use "await", the program not send request to service and not show any response in endpoint service.

case 2 I've use await it worked normally, but if endpoint service not available the main service shown "Internal Server Error".

Thank you for Advance

Comment: If the issue is that the endpoint service is not available (i.e. the destination of your `client.post` call), you probably want to catch the exception that gets thrown and give a proper response back instead of letting it bubble up and cause an internal server error? Is that the issue?

Comment: Probably not, I'd like to send request only, not to check anything and not want to receive any response from endpoint. but if I not use "await" to execute async def in main app, it not to send anything to endpoint service

Comment: You'll have to use `await`, but you can wrap it in a `try` / `except` clause to swallow any exceptions. I strongly recommend logging any failures however, otherwise you won't have any idea of what's happening or if anything has failed at all.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating/removing the HTTPClient? to take advantage of keep alive connections you could have a global http_client as follow:

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Union

from aiosonic import HTTPClient

from fastapi import FastAPI

client = HTTPClient()


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(_app: FastAPI):
    global client
    yield
    # useful function to wait all pending requests to finish
    await client.wait_requests()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/")
async def home():
    assert client, "no client"
    url = "https://postman-echo.com/post"
    res = await client.post(url, params={"foo": "bar"})
    return (await res.json())["args"]
```

But your error seems to be at the server you're targeting. Remember to place the traceback if possible in the stackoverflow question.