# What is the proper way to make downstream Https requests inside of Uvicorn/FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, starlette, httpx

I have an API endpoint (FastAPI / Uvicorn). Among other things, it makes a request to yet another API for information. When I load my API with multiple concurrent requests, I begin to receive the following error:

```
h11._util.LocalProtocolError: can't handle event type ConnectionClosed when role=SERVER and state=SEND_RESPONSE
```

In a normal environment, I would take advantage of `request.session`, but I understand it not to be fully thread safe.

Thus, what is the proper approach to using requests within a framework such as FastAPI, where multiple threads would be using the `requests` library at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `requests`, you could use [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org), which offers an [`async` API](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) as well ([`httpx` is also suggested in FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/#httpx) when performing `async` tests, as well as FastAPI/Starlette recently [replaced the HTTP client on `TestClient` from `requests` to `httpx`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/commit/6765502c1e5a418c16bb379c54b8ea706b0444cf)).

The below example is based on the one given in [`httpx` documentation](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#streaming-responses), demonstrating how to use the library for making an asynchronous HTTP(s) request, and subsequently, streaming the response back to the client. The [`httpx.AsyncClient()`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests) is what you can use instead of `requests.Session()`, which is useful when several requests are being made to the same host, as the underlying TCP connection will be reused, instead of recreating one for every single request—hence, resulting in a significant performance improvement. Additionally, it allows you to reuse `headers` and other settings (such as `proxies` and `timeout`), as well as persist `cookies`, across requests. You spawn a `Client` and reuse it every time you need it. You can use `await client.aclose()` to [explicitly close the client](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients) once you are done with it (you could do that inside a [`shutdown` event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#shutdown-event) handler). Examples and more details can also be found in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804).

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import httpx


app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    app.state.client = httpx.AsyncClient()


@app.on_event('shutdown')
async def shutdown_event():
    await app.state.client.aclose()


@app.get('/')
async def home():
    client = app.state.client
    req = client.build_request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/')
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(r.aiter_raw(), background=BackgroundTask(r.aclose))
```

### Example (Updated)

Since [`startup` and `shutdown` have now been deprecated](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated) (and might be completely removed in the future), you could instead use a [`lifespan` handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan) to  initialise the `httpx` Client, as well as close the Client instance on shutdown, similar to what has been demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804). Starlette specifically provides an example using a `lifespan` handler and `httpx` Client in their documentation page. As described in [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/lifespan/#lifespan-state):

> The `lifespan` has the concept of `state`, which is a dictionary that
> can be used to **share the objects** between the lifespan, and the
> requests.
>
> The `state` received on the requests is a shallow copy of the state
> received on the lifespan handler.

Hence, objects added to the state in the lifespan handler can be accessed inside endpoints using `request.state`. The example below uses a streaming response to both communicate with the external server, as well as send the response back to the client. See [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#streaming-responses) for more details on the `async` response streaming methods of `httpx` (i.e., `aiter_bytes()`, `aiter_text()`, `aiter_lines()`, etc.).

If you would like to use a `media_type` for the `StreamingResponse`, you could use the one from the original response like this: `media_type=r.headers['content-type']`. However, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804), you need to make sure that the `media_type` is not set to `text/plain`; otherwise, the content would not stream as expected in the browser, unless you disable *MIME Sniffing* (have a look at the linked answer for more details and solutions).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
import httpx


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    req = client.build_request('GET', 'https://www.example.com')
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(r.aiter_raw(), background=BackgroundTask(r.aclose))
```

If, for any reason, you need to **read the content chunk by chunk** on server side before responding back to the client, you could do this as follows:

```py
@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    req = client.build_request('GET', 'https://www.example.com')
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    
    async def gen():
        async for chunk in r.aiter_raw():
            yield chunk
        await r.aclose()
        
    return StreamingResponse(gen())
```

If you don't want to use a streaming response, but rather **have `httpx` reading the response for you** in the first place (which would store the response data to the server's RAM; hence, you should make sure there is enough space available to accommodate the data), you could use the following. Note that using `r.json()` should only apply to cases where the response data are in JSON format; otherwise, you could return a [`PlainTextResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#plaintextresponse) or a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) directly, as demonstrated below.

```py
from fastapi import Response
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    req = client.build_request('GET', 'https://www.example.com')
    r = await client.send(req)
    content_type = r.headers.get('content-type')
    
    if content_type == 'application/json':
        return r.json()
    elif content_type == 'text/plain':
        return PlainTextResponse(content=r.text)
    else:
        return Response(content=r.content)
```

---

Using the `async` API of `httpx` would mean that you have to define your endpoints with `async def`; otherwise, you would have to use the [standard synchronous API](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/) (for `def` vs `async def` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)), and as described in [this github discussion](https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/1633#discussioncomment-717658):

> Yes. `HTTPX` **is intended to be thread-safe,** and yes, a single
> client-instance across all threads will do better in terms of
> connection pooling, than using an instance-per-thread.

You can also control the connection pool size using the `limits` keyword argument on the `Client` (see [Pool limit configuration](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#pool-limit-configuration)). For example:

```py
limits = httpx.Limits(max_keepalive_connections=5, max_connections=10)
client = httpx.Client(limits=limits)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try it out right away. If it does the trick, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: No, sorry -- been a really busy week -- still trying to get to implementation.