# Error 500 when calling Post method using FastAPI on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, python-requests, fastapi, vercel

I'm using React on the frontend and Fastapi on the backend

> main.py

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
   CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = ["*"],
    allow_credentials =True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers= ["*"],
)

class LoginItem(BaseModel):
    access_token: str

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.post("/api/check-login")
async def check_login(input_token: LoginItem):
    s = requests.Session()
    data = jsonable_encoder(input_token)
    url_checklogin = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/contexts/me/?header=True"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data['access_token']
    }
    req = s.get(url_checklogin,headers=headers).json()

    return req
```

> App.jsx

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const url_login = "https://backen-udemycoupon.vercel.app/api/check-login";

    const res = await axios.post(url_login, {
      access_token: "test",
    });

    console.log("check login", res.data);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <span onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Click</span>
    </main>
  );
}
```

When I run on localhost with the path. Everything works fine:

http://localhost:8000/api/check-login

When I change it to https://backen-udemycoupon.vercel.app/api/check-login I get error 500

At first I thought the post method had a problem. So I tried writing another post method in the main.py file

```
@app.post("/api/token")
async def check_login(token: LoginItem):
    return token
```

and edit the path in App.jsx

```
...
const url_login = "https://backen-udemycoupon.vercel.app/api/token";
...
```

But it works well

So I don't know if it's because the requests library is not supported in fastapi or because Udemy blocks it (although it runs fine on localhost).

How to fix?.

Thank you

Comment: Do you see something in server logs after you get 500 error?

Comment: This is the log file I exported on Vercel when I received error 500

https://helurl.com/drive/s/mt9LIAVp6n3fTTv9jo2MU9VSVUlEc4

Comment: On a side note, you should be using an HTTP client library, such as `httpx` instead of `requests`, that offers an `async` API as well. Executing blocking operations within `async def` endpoints - that is exactly what your endpoint currently does when using `requests` - would block the event loop, and hence, the entire server. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) for more details.

Comment: To simplify you can just change endpoint's defenition form `async def` to `def` since you don't use any async functions in your endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should confirm that the response status code is `200` (indicating that the request had succeeded), before calling the `.json()` method on the response.

```py
@app.post("/api/check-login")
async def check_login(input_token: LoginItem):
    s = requests.Session()
    data = jsonable_encoder(input_token)
    url_checklogin = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/contexts/me/?header=True"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data['access_token']
    }
    resp = s.get(url_checklogin,headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.json()
    else:
        return {"status_code": resp.status_code, "text": resp.text}
```

Comment: I no longer get the 500 error but instead get the 403 Forbidden error. Even though I tried running "access_token" on localhost, I still logged in normally.

Comment: It means that the `GET` request from your backend to `https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/contexts/me/?header=True` returns `403 Forbidden error`. It seems like your question is more related to Udemy API and I can't help you here.

Comment: I don't understand why on "localhost" it returns code 405 but still logs in normally

Comment: This is already another question.. Try reading API docs and following instructions