# aiohttp connection closing before FastAPI Streaming Response

Tags: fastapi, aiohttp

I've got a FastAPI app with a route that calls an external API with aiohttp. The external API streams the response, and I'd like to stream my response as well. Here's a simplified version of the router I'm using.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import aiohttp

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/")
async def proxy_stream():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as http_session:
        async with http_session.post(
            "https://streaming-api",
            json={"json": "body"}
        ) as response:
            
            async def process_response():
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(128):
                    # Work on chunk and then stream it
                    yield process_chunk(chunk)

            return StreamingResponse(
                process_response()
            )
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectionError: Connection closed' errors. It seems the response is being read outside of its context manager, but not sure how I could solve that.

Any tips?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) on how to properly make HTTP requests inside a FastAPI application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the return statement, the context managers are closed and the session is no longer active

To avoid this you can create session inside your generator function:

```
@router.post("/")
async def proxy_stream():

    async def process_response():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as http_session:
            async with http_session.post(
                "https://streaming-api",
                json={"json": "body"}
            ) as response:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(128):
                    # Work on chunk and then stream it
                    yield process_chunk(chunk)

           
    return StreamingResponse(
        process_response()
    )
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was unclear on async context managers and when they exit. It seems a bit unintuitive, but makes sense. Thanks!