# How to configure two microservices using Python (uvicorn/fastapi/requests) to call each other in one use case?

Tags: python, rest, microservices, fastapi, uvicorn

I have two microservices. Let's name them `service1` and `service2`.
I have implemened an endpoint on `service1` which calls an endpoint from `service2`. To fullfill this request, an endpoint from `service2` needs some data from `service1`, so **it calls another endpoint** from `service1`. And usually this works fine and both services are getting 200 REST responses, so there is no issue.

BUT sometimes one of the microservices receives wrong data or there is some network issue and then **both microservices freeze and the pods on kubernetes restarts. From the user's perspective it throws a 502 (bad gateway) error in the web browser.** In the logs I can see that requests POST is made, but then nothing more is logged and I can only see uvicorn's startup logs, something like this:

```
INFO:     Started server process [1490]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

To be more precise, both microservices use FastAPI as a main framework and they are running on Python's uvicorn and the requests are posted with standard "requests" package like this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.example.com/some-endpoint'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)
```

So my question is - **how to configure both microservices to avoid such situations?** Is there any flag in uvicorn or requests that I can specify to prevent apps from crashing like this?
Or maybe is there a differnt method of comunications for such use case like queues in RabbitMQ or something similar? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: On a side note, please consider using a library that offers `async` API as well, such as `httpx` instead of `requests`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Add a timeout to the HTTP call, make sure exceptions are properly handled and if such outages happen regularly consider implementing circuit breakers.

Comment: Wrap you code in `try .. except` block and log the error message

Comment: It seems more like a design problem, rather than a framework problem. I would try to change the dependency so that both rely on a third service, instead of each other recursively

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to my issue. I took good advices from the comments and then I've added some of my own code after many trials and errors.

So to fix the issue I had to do the following:

1. Add "timeout" value to my POST requests

```
x = requests.post(url, json = myobj, timeout=5)
```

2. Replace uvicorn with gunicorn and set number of workers greater than 1 and then add gunicorn to my "init script" for k8s deployment

```
gunicorn --workers=3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker service.app:app;
```

3. Set resources on k8s to greater values. Too low resources may cause gunicorn to fail start workers

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 50m
          memory: 128Mi
```

4. (optionally) Scale number of replicas on k8s to 2 for each microservice.