# Can i update lifespan in fastapi without restarting the app

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to update values in `lifespan` of fastapi.
This is the code

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
   names = requests.get(url).json()
    yield
```

Let say i knew that the response of API has been updated. Is there a way I can update the value name in `lifespan` without stopping and starting the app.

May be just creating another endpoint, upon calling the value of `names` in `lifespan` event got override.
Thanks

Comment: Refactor it to a separate function, then call that from your lifespan function and from the endpoint (or use a scheduler such as apscheduler) call the same function?

Comment: lifespan event will only be called when app start. i cant call it again. so once the app start, the names cant be changed even though the response of api change. because i could not find a way to call lifespan event without restarting the app

Comment: Yes, so refactor the functionality out to a separate function or class, then call that from your lifespan function _and_ from the other location when you want to update the information stored.

Comment: look like i did not understand you well. let say i created an other function `get_vector_store_name` if i call this function via endpoint, will it update the value in `lifespan` event.

Comment: No, but your `lifespan` function calls `get_vector_store_names` and that function does whatever it wants to do - either store it in a module variable, keep it inside a class (with the function as a method inside the class), or wherever. You also then call that function from the endpoint or scheduled task that updates the stored information inside your application.

Comment: got that. so you are saying just call `lifespan` function via an endpoint.

Comment: but this did not worked. i call it inside an endpoint `app_lifespan(app)` but nothing changed

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should move what you have inside your lifespan function to a separate function, and call that, both from the lifespan function and from your endpoint. You also need to make sure that you're updating the correct variable - as you've written it now, nothing is done with the `names` variable, it's just assigned inside your function and never made available in any way. You have to import it to the function by using `global` if you need to update a variable outside of your function (or wrap it in a class and call the method on an object instead).

Comment: @TalhaAnwar On a side note, you should avoid calling blocking functions - such as those provided by the `requests` library - inside `async def` functions. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details. Instead, you should rather use a library that provides an `async` API, such as `httpx`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804)